# PhpStorm doesn't recognize laravel namespace after building docker image

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, dockerfile, phpstorm

I am setting up a new Laravel project and automating the installation process using docker.

Everything works, but the problem here is that the PhpStorm doesn't recognize some namespaces **because the `vendor` folder is a volume**. I will show the files to understand them better.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-8080}:80'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
            - /var/www/html/vendor     #HERE IS THE VOLUME FOR VENDOR
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.1.2-fpm

#INSTALL DEPENDENCIES
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openssl \
    build-essential \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    locales \
    apt-transport-https \
    wget \
    lsb-release \
    libxml2-dev \
    ca-certificates \
    git \
    nano \
    libonig-dev \
    zip

#PGSQL
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql

#Libraries required for Laravel
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo_mysql \
    bcmath \
    ctype \
    fileinfo \
    iconv \
    gd \
    mbstring \
    pdo_mysql \
    xml \
    pcntl

# Install composer
RUN php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

COPY ./ /var/www/html

# Copy code to $path
RUN composer install

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

**.dockerignore**

```
vendor
```

So after building the image and running `composer install`, the `vendor` folder is created in the container with all dependencies and in the host machine but without subfolders, as we can see in the following image:

[image]

And when I try to import any namespace, I receive an error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong in PHPStorm. Your `vendor` folder is empty.

I used to run `docker-composer` without mapping *volume* for `vendor`.

---

Remove the mapping and log in to service with `bash` and run the `composer install`

**Steps**

1. Remove the `- /var/www/html/vendor` volume mapping
2. Log in to service using `docker exec -it laravel.test bash` (FYI: It's better if you use `container_name:` search it.)

   - run the command `composer install` or `composer update`

> Note: Before running remove the existing vendor folder.(delete or rename it `_vendor` for temp)

---

> > **Wild guess**: check you volums whether you defined `volume`.